# Python if x in y

Tags: python

```
if "test" in ['testtext', 'aaaa', 'texttext']:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

This will always output "no". How can I change this so it outputs "yes" as the word "test" is present in 'testtext' even though it's just a portion of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `any()` builtin function:

```
if any("test" in w for w in ['testtext', 'aaaa', 'texttext']):
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Prints:

```
yes
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also try with [operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) builtin module  with operator.contains

```
txt = ['testtext', 'aaaa', 'texttext']

[operator.contains(i,'test') for i in txt]
```

output:

```
[True, False, False]
```

if u want get word which is true. 
first convert ur txt file in numpy array then then try this.

```
txt = np.array(txt)
x = [operator.contains(i,'test') for i in txt]
txt[x]
```

output:

```
array(['testtext'], dtype='<U8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code with `for` loop to get result:-

```
for var in ['hello', 'testtext', 'aaaa', 'texttext']:
    if "test" in var:
        print("yes")
        break
else:
    print("no")
```

**Output**

```
yes
```